# Restrirct Boundary 320 x 480, while scaling UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on Interior Decoration Application, we can add Sofa, Table, Chair Table Lamp on Camera screen then can scale UIImage with touch to zoom picture. But by zooming we don't want to increase UIImage Size greater then 320 x 480, I mean want to restrict in iphone Boundary.

any suggestion, I had implemented and tried, but couldn't get exact solution. I use to check on base of center but this approach is not working, want some thing like Edge detection may be that would be exact solution,

Already Thanks, looking forwards

here is some code that I am using to Resize my UIImageView

```
-(BOOL)isValidSizeForView:(UIView *)myView forSize:(CGSize)size
{
    BOOL Decision = NO;

    CGRect rect = myView.frame;

    CGRect BoundRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    float MinX = (BoundRect.origin.x+(myView.frame.size.width/2));

    float MaxX = ((BoundRect.origin.x+BoundRect.size.width)-(myView.frame.size.width/2));

    float MinY = (BoundRect.origin.y+(myView.frame.size.height/2));

    float MaxY = ((BoundRect.origin.y+BoundRect.size.height)-(myView.frame.size.height/2));

    if(rect.origin.x > MinX && rect.origin.x< MaxX && rect.origin.y> MinY && rect.origin.y<MaxY)
    {
        Decision = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        printf(":( no sorry \n");
    }

    return Decision;
}
```

Comment: how do you scale that image ??? paste some code...

Comment: above is code how I am restricting boundary, please go through it and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the maximum zoomed size for your image by doing something like this:

```
- (CGSize)zoomedSizeForImage:(UIImage *)image constrainedTo:(CGSize)maxSize {
    CGFloat width = image.size.width;
    CGFloat height = image.size.height;
    if (width > maxSize.width) {
        width = maxSize.width;
        height = height * maxSize.width / width;
    }
    if (height > maxSize.height) {
        width = width * maxSize.height / height;
        height = maxSize.height;
    }
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

Comment: I really really appreciate your reply, this code is fine unless we dont resize image with UITouch. but when we scale/resize UIImage using Touch, we can't restrict it into boundary, although touch get abnormal. any suggestion??

Comment: I'm not sure I undersand the issue.  It seems to me that you could check the size in `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, and if it's larger than the maximum zoomed size, scale it down in an animation block.